# If $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n -1}{n\sqrt{n}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

> If $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n -1}{n\sqrt{n}}$ is.

Here since  $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n -1}{n\sqrt{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}} =0$$

$$ \because \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0 \,\,\,\,\And\,\,\,\,  \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}} =0 $$

I wanted to verify if my method is correct because the answer for this in the solution key is -1.

Comment: $0$ is the correct answer.